# Recyclerview row color issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want the `recyclerview` must work like `facebook` `videoview` list.I have added a footer at the end of the `recyclerview` items just like `facebook`. everything is working fine except the row color change is not working. I want the middle item view must be transparent and other items must be black in color on scroll of the `recyclerview`

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/videoTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Category"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/videoDate"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="Date"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shareButton"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/share" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/addedon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="addedOn"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- videoView layout-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/videoFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/videoRelativelayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <VideoView
                        android:id="@+id/videoplayer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center" />

                    <!-- mediaControls layout-->
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/mediaControls"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="50dp"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="50dp"-->
                        <!--android:layout_gravity="center">-->

                        <!--<ImageView-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/videoPlay"-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                        <!--android:clickable="true"-->
                        <!--android:contentDescription="@string/description"-->
                        <!--android:src="@drawable/play_icon" />-->

                        <!--<ImageView-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/videoPause"-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                        <!--android:clickable="true"-->
                        <!--android:contentDescription="@string/description"-->
                        <!--android:src="@drawable/pause_icon" />-->
                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

                        <!--<TextView-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/lblCurrentPosition"-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
                        <!--android:text="@string/empty_message"-->
                        <!--android:textColor="#FFF" />-->
                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_progress"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:max="100"
                            android:maxHeight="1000dp"
                            android:minHeight="2dip"
                            android:progress="0"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
                            android:thumbOffset="0px" />


                        <!--<TextView-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/lblRemainingPosition"-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
                        <!--android:text="@string/empty_message"-->
                        <!--android:textColor="#FFF" />-->
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblCurrentPosition"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="@string/empty_message"
                            android:textColor="#FFF" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/fullscreen"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:src="@drawable/fullscreen" />

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/imagePreviewLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/abovePlayButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="1"></LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/playButton"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_big" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/pause_white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/playMain"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/play" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/replay"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/replay" />



                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/belowPlayButton"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/desc_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:maxLines="100"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

-->
    -->

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/listLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:paddingStart="20dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/videoRecyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="150dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @RicardoBarroca my xml layout contains the videoview and Textviews.

Comment: We can't guess whats wrong if you have nothing to show but words!

Comment: @RicardoBarroca I have added my xml here